# A Python code of a program that reads an integer, and prints the integer it is a multiple of either 2 or 5 but not both

Tags: python-3.x

A Python code of a program that reads an integer, and prints the integer is a multiple of either 2 or 5 but not both.

Answer (score 3):

First off, SO is not a forum to ask people to solve your homework without first putting effort yourself. you could have written a simple naive solution with if-else statements and posted that in your question, asking for a better way to do this.

That being said, I'm still adding my approach because I think you should know that a beautiful and simple way would be to just use an **XOR** check:

```
n = int(input("Input a number: "))
answer = True if (n % 2 == 0) != (n % 5 == 0) else False
print(answer)
```

I'm assuming the user will always input a value that can be cast as an integer. You can take care of the error handling process. Once the number has been read, I do a simple XOR check to return True if the number is only divisible by either 2 or 5 but not both, and False in all other cases. This works because `bool(a)!=bool(b)` gives `True` only when `bool(a)` and `bool(b)` evaluate to different things.

Demonstration:

```
def check(n):
    return (n%2 == 0) != (n%5 ==0)

print(check(2)) # Out: True
print(check(5)) # Out: True
print(check(10)) # Out: False
print(check(3)) # Out: False
```